# Accented characters in path for nsurl nsdata

Tags: ios, objective-c, special-characters, nsdata, nsurl

I have problem with following piece of code. I would like to use accented path in my file name string.

```
NSString *filePath = @"http://mypath.com/fileöä.pdf";
NSString *urlFilePath = [filePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlFilePath];
    if(!url) {
        return;
    }
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if(! data) {
        return;
    }
```

i get data as nil pointer, can any one suggest me how to fix this, can we not get data using any other way, if the urlFilePath has accented characters.

Comment: Which is `nil`? `url` or `data`? If `data`, then use the `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` method so you can see what the error is.

Comment: po error
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file "fileöä.pdf" couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=http://mypath.com/fileo%CC%88a%CC%88.pdf},data pointer is nil, but if i give a normal path which have no accented string it works fine, it has only problem with accented chars like ö, ä.

Comment: Does the exact same URL work in your computer's browser?

Comment: no it does not load if it has accented char in the path, for other files, it is working fine,

Comment: If you can't load the file from your browser, no code you write is going to work.